# matrix not seen as numeric R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

So I converted my data frame to as.matrix(df):

```
m<-as.matrix(df)
```

But then:

```
> is.numeric(m)
[1] FALSE
```

I even tried to see if a certain single factor in the matrix is numeric:

```
> is.numeric(m[15,15])
[1] FALSE
```

Anyone else had this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
dims <- dim(m)
m <- as.numeric(m)
dim(m) <- dims
```

Probably want to wrap the above in a function

---

`as.matrix` will not necessarily convert any arbitrary data.frame to numeric.
eg:

```
x <- data.frame(LETTERS)
m <- as.matrix(x)
is.numeric(x) 
# [1] FALSE
is.character(x) 
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: m<-as.numeric(m) gave me a list of all the values in my original matrix. Not that helpful.

Comment: I figured it out, but your way works too. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the joys of `R` data types.

A matrix in `R` has twp special properties: every column must be the same length, and every element must have the same data type. So you can have a matrix of characters, or a matrix of numbers, but you can't have a matrix with both.

Now, suppose you have a data frame, `df`, with two columns, `A` and `B`. `A` has characters and `B` has numbers. This is fine for data frames. But now you do:

```
 m <- as.matrix(df)
```

As @Sven points out below, the resulting data type of the matrix is based on the most general one (character > numeric > integer > logical). `R` will coerce everything else to that data type in `m`. And it will not warn you (unless the coercion creates `NA's`, which is possible).

Comment: The resulting data type of the matrix is not based on the first data type but on the most general one (character > numeric > integer > logical).